# listview- System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, listview, outofrangeexception, subitem

I have a listview which has 7 columns. I want to add information on each column, but when it reaches the subitem 2 from the listView I get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` even though I have that subitem.

Any idea why I get this error? I've tried to search for it but I haven't found a similar case.
This is the part of the code where I get that error:

```
if (seen == true)
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Tag = "Seen";
        else
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Tag = "Not Seen";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not have **all** those SubItems in **each** item.

Or maybe nothing is selected? (Note that the `SelectionChanged` event gets called when an `Item` is **unselected** as well!)

Note that every `Item` in a `ListView` can have **its own number** of **SubItems**, no matter how many `Columns` you have created. These only provide a space to **display** the data, not slots you can access without creating `SubItems` !

Therefore we must test it before we access it! In other words: The `ListView` structure is **not a 2d array but a jagged array**!

This could be a possible check..:

```
if ( listView1.SelectedItems[0].Count > 0 &&     
     listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems.Count > 2 )
   listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Tag = seen ?  "Seen" :  "Not Seen";
```

..but you know your code better and may well find a nicer way of doing the necessary tests..

Just do not rely on the number of `SubItems` being equal to the number of `Columns`. They are not related at all and **either** may be greater in each `Item`!

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but what do I have to change in order to have access to those subitems? Beacause the purpose is to fill each of those fields with data.  Thank you!

Comment: They must __exist__, so you need to __create/add__ each. But maybe the error was in the `SelectedItems[0]`? Use the debugger to find out which of the two indexers throws the exception!